# How to compare date fields between two tables and get the less or equal date from the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table A and table B. Both of them have date fields. I need compare those fields and get a table C with the less or equal date between Table A and table B, taking into account that the table A is the main.

> **CONTEXT:** I have in Table A Expiration of products, and in table B on business days. The user can update table B when it is determined
>   that a date is not to be considered as a "business day". Then delete
>   the date from table B and then go to table A to update all product
>   expirations that were registered with that date and assign them the
>   previous business day. So in my case I am creating table C, which
>   contains the Id of table A and the working date less or equal to the
>   date mentioned. Then I will make the respective update.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpA
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpB


CREATE TABLE #tmpA(Id INT IDENTITY(100,1),Fecha date)

INSERT INTO #tmpA(Fecha)
VALUES
('20170101'),('20171003'),('20170504'),('2017-09-01')

SELECT * FROM #tmpA

Id          Fecha
----------- ----------
100         2017-01-01
101         2017-10-03
102         2017-05-04
103         2017-09-01

CREATE TABLE #tmpB(Id INT IDENTITY(1,4),Fecha date)

INSERT INTO #tmpB(Fecha)
VALUES
('20170101'),('20171001'),('20170504')

SELECT * FROM #tmpB

Id          Fecha
----------- ----------
1           2017-01-01
5           2017-10-01
9           2017-05-04
```

I want to get this result (**The same number of records in table A**):

```
Id          Fecha
----------- ----------
100         2017-01-01
101         2017-10-01 --> **this row is less than 2017-10-03**
102         2017-05-04
103         2017-05-04 --> **this row is less than 2017-09-01**
```

I tried to built some queries without results,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpC') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpC
SELECT A.* INTO #tmpC FROM #tmpA A LEFT JOIN #tmpB B ON A.Fecha = B.Fecha WHERE  B.Fecha IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #tmpC 

SELECT *
FROM #tmpA A INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #tmpC
    GROUP BY id, Fecha

) AS Q ON MAX(Q.Fecha) <= A.Fecha
```

UPDATE:

**NOTE. The Id column is simply an identity, but it does not mean that it should be related. The important thing is the dates.**

Regards

Comment: very well explained.

Comment: Can you please explain the UPDATE which you just provided? How do you plan on joining these tables if the ID column is irrelevant?

Comment: Hi @Eli, Because the Id column is simply an identity, but it does not mean that it should be related. The important thing is the dates. I just updated my question with different Id. Please check my question.

Comment: @JotaPardo What stops the logic from comparing every value in table A to every value in Table B? There seems to be some more data/columns in your tables which you haven't put into the question.

Comment: @Eli, Thanks for your interest. Actually the additional fields are not relevant to the solution, but to put in context I will update the question. Basically the context is that I have in Table A Expiration of products, and in table B on business days. The user can update table B when it is determined that a date is not to be considered as a "business day". [continue...]

Comment: @Eli, [continue..] Then delete the date from table B and then go to table A to update all product expirations that were registered with that date and assign them the previous business day. However, it is not enough just to assign the previous business day recorded in table B. So in my case I am creating table C, which contains the Id of table A and the working date less or equal to the date mentioned. Then I will make the respective update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure if this will scale well (if you have more than 100k rows) this will bring back the results which you want.
Theoretically, the correct way for you to do this, in a fashion which *will* scale well, would be to have a view where you utilize RANK() and join both of these tables together, though this was the quick and easy way. Please try this and let me know if it meets your requirements.
For your edification, I have left both of the dates in there for you to be able to compare them.

```
SELECT
    A.ID
    ,A.FECHA OLDDATE
    ,B.FECHA CORRECTDATE
FROM #TMPA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TMPB B ON 1=1
WHERE 1=1 
AND B.FECHA = (
    SELECT MAX(FECHA)
    FROM #TMPB
    WHERE FECHA <= A.FECHA)
```

Comment: I tested with 1K rows and I got more rows than Table A rows. However, Thats correct! Just add 'DISTINCT' stament.

Comment: Why do you use 'WHERE 1=1'?

Comment: Glad that this works (remember to mark as answer). As for the Where 1=1; it is a habit of mine, as I often comment out where clauses for testing purposes, case in point, and when you don't have a where 1=1 you may need a lot more editing to enable the second where clause instead of the first one. I take it out in production, though in development it is usually there.

Comment: Please don´t forget to add the DISTICT word in your answer.

Comment: The only reason why you would need distinct would be if you had duplicates in table B. Can you check those 1k rows to see if they exist? Based on your description of table B there shouldn't be any duplicates there at all.

Comment: you right! I was testing this code with duplicate dates in table B, but in real life it does not exist duplicate dates.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.id,
       (case when b.fecha < a.fecha then b.fecha else a.fecha end) as fecha
from #tmpA a left join
     #tmpB b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, thank you for your answer. However, in my case for example if I add '20170901' to the table A, I would expect the result '20170504' from table B, because is the less than '20170901'

Answer (score 0):

You can get minmum by union all

```
select id, min(fecha) from (
   select * from #tmpA
     union all
   select * from #tmpB
  ) a
 group by a.id
```

Comment: Hi Kandasamy, thank you for your answer. However, in my case for example if I add '20170901' to the table A, I would expect the result '20170504' from table B, because is the less than '20170901'

Answer (score 0):

@JotaPardo WHERE 1=1 is used to basically make sure the query runs if the WHERE conditions don't hold up. 1=1 will equate to true so saying WHERE 1=1 or WHERE TRUE, and TRUE is always TRUE, ensures the query will have at least one WHERE clause condition that will always hold up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31088813)